# Reference request: an introduction to triangular, square, and other figurate numbers

Tags: reference-request, primary-education, number-theory

There are dozens (maybe thousands) of websites that explain what triangular numbers, square numbers, etc. are. I'm searching for a *printed book* that includes this material, preferably at a level that would be appropriate for an elementary school-aged student (i.e., someone 11 or younger).  It's not typically found in elementary school textbooks or other curricula, so this would probably need to be a "Cool Math"-type of extracurricular book.  Does anybody know of such a source?

Comment: Is it required to be in print and readily available for purchase?

Comment: @shoover Not necessarily, out-of-print books are fine.

Comment: A google books search for ["figurate numbers"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22figurate+numbers%22&tbm=bks) led me to [**Figurate Numbers**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/9814355488) by Michel Deza and Elena Deza, although this book is almost certainly too advanced for your needs. Also, most every older recreational math book before the 1950s or so has a section on figurate numbers, such as Hogben's **Mathematics for the Million** and Ball's **Mathematical Recreations and Essays**, and many such books can be found on university library shelves.

Comment: I recommend The Number Devil, by Hans Enzensberger. Chapter 5 is about triangular numbers. But that's the only chapter on figurate numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a publication in the ERIC archive called [*Recreational Mathematics*](https://archive.org/details/ERIC_ED035550/page/n161/mode/2up?q=%22triangular+numbers%22+)*, authored by William L. Schaaf, that is a bibliography of books and journal articles about recreational mathematics, organized by topic. A search in this document for "triangular numbers" yields quite a few results, for example, a page of books about "number curiosities":

[image: triangular numbers]

A specific book that treats triangular numbers is Martin Gardner's [*Mathematical Carnival*](https://archive.org/details/mathematicalcarn00gard/page/196/mode/2up), which starts from Pascal's Triangle and shows the different sorts of numbers that can be extracted from it. As Gardner puts it, "the pattern is so simple that a 10-year-old can write it down."

[image: Gardner]

I suggest a search through ERIC for some more recent references, or a search through the Internet Archive for some possibly older ones, may result in a list of suitable books. Some of the "out of print" books may have been revived in an affordable Dover printing.

*Not to be confused with the now-defunct [*Journal of Recreational Mathematics*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journal_of_Recreational_Mathematics) or the newer journal called [*Recreational Mathematics Magazine*](https://sciendo.com/journal/RMM)!

Comment: In addition to the places above, a useful reference to keep in mind for things like this is the 4-volume **A Bibliography of Recreational Mathematics** by William Leonard Schaaf [Volume 1](https://archive.org/details/ERIC_ED121622) (also [here](https://eric.ed.gov/?id=ED121622)) and [Volume 2](https://archive.org/details/ERIC_ED040874) (also [here](https://eric.ed.gov/?id=ED040874)) and [Volume 3](https://archive.org/details/ERIC_ED087631). I can't find a digital copy of Volume 4 (I have print copies of all volumes), but in it you'd want to look at Section 2.4: *Figurate numbers* on pp. 25-28.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro The first page image above is from Schaaf.

Comment: I realized this after I wrote my comment, when I clicked on your link. In fact, I initially thought you were referring to an issue of [Journal of Recreational Mathematics](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Journal+of+Recreational+Mathematics%22), and only later realized this was the 3rd edition of Schaaf's bibliography. Note that my links are to the 4th edition (1970 for Volumes 1 and 2, 1973 for Volume 3; FYI, Volume 4 appeared in 1978). And while I'm here, I may as well mention [David Singmaster's pages](https://www.puzzlemuseum.com/singma/singma-index.htm) for those not familiar with them.